# How to change the text of a Button in recyclerview when adapter class is loading second time?

Tags: java, android

This is what I want according to picture
[image]

I am sharing my code

Model Class

```
 class Msg{
 private Boolean BtnName;

public Boolean getBtnName() {
    return BtnName;
}

public void setBtnName(Boolean btnName) {
    BtnName = btnName;
}
}
```

AdapterClass:

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final TeachersTodayScheduleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    mTeacherScheduleArrayList.get(position).setBtnName(false);
    holder.btn_checkin.setTag(position);
    holder.btn_checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Object data = v.getTag();
            if (data != null) {
                // I have set the Boolean value to true after clicking this particular button, but whn the arraylist again loading, the boolean value disaapear
                mTeacherScheduleArrayList.get(position).setBtnName(true);

            if(mFlagtrue!=null && mFlagtrue.contentEquals("flag_true"))
    {
        if(mTeacherScheduleArrayList.get(position).getBtnName().equals(true))// when it return true, then below colde work, this is not happening
        {
            holder.btn_checkin.setText("Attended");
            holder.btn_checkin.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green_btn);
            holder.btn_checkin.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong, please help, 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final TeachersTodayScheduleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    mTeacherScheduleArrayList.get(position).setBtnName(false); // <<<<<<
    .......
```

You're setting the value to false every time the view is bound. Remove this line.

Comment: TeacherScheduleArrayList.get(position).setBtnName(false);  -> this making the boolean value to false at first loading, and when clicked on button, that postion becoming true, 
When the adapter class is second time loading its removing all its previous value and allocation new value,

Comment: No it's setting it to false *every* time the view is created, including after you've clicked the button. If you scroll the view offscreen and then scroll back to it, this line will set it back to `false`.